# Displaying file name using special characters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've one file *ABC_123.csv* in my *app* directory and I want to display its full name. I found two ways to do it (see below code snippet): one using **???** and the other using **asterisk** at the end of required text **ABC_**.

But, both ways are also displaying the path along with the name. Both below commands are producing results in this format: **path + name**. I only need the **name**. Is there any special character (like ? or *) to display the name file only?

```
[input]$ ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv
[output] /usr/opt/app/ABC_123.csv

[input]$ ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_*.csv
[output] /usr/opt/app/ABC_123.csv
```

I cannot do this:

```
[input]$ cd /usr/opt/app
[input]$ ls ABC_???.csv
[output] ABC_123.csv
```

Required output:

```
[input]$ ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_(some-special-character).csv
[output] ABC_123.csv
```

[Edited] `basename` is working, but, I want to achieve this using `ls` and `some special character` (as highlighted above in Required output). Is there any way to this?

```
[input]$ basename /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv
[output] ABC_123.csv
```

Comment: What does `basename /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv` return?

Comment: What does `basename /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv | hexdump -C` return? Please add this to your question (no comment).

Comment: Added. Due to some server restrictions, I can only use `ls`.

Comment: Why don't you do a `ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_*.csv`, or - perhaps simpler - a `echo ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_*.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
find /usr/opt/app/ -type f -name "ABC_*.csv" -exec basename '{}' \;
```

`basename` will isolate the file name. `find` will search the specified directory for files that match the provided pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you were limited to `ls`, then this might help.

```sh
file="$(echo /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv)"; echo "${file##*/}"
```

Comment: Will not work when multiple files matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe every csv file to `basename`:

```
ls /usr/opt/app/ABC_*.csv | xargs basename -a
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a need for basename:

```
(cd /usr/opt/app/ && ls ABC_*.csv)
```

"I cannot do this" was similar but didn't explain why, so maybe one-liner is doable. Doing in sub-shell prevents current dir from changing.

And no - there is no special character that could be used there. It's globbing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`:

```sh
files=( /usr/opt/app/ABC_???.csv ) # Expands to array of matching filename(s)
printf "%s\n" "${file[@]##*/}"
```

The `##` part of the expansion removes the longest leading string that matches the following pattern from each element of the array (So it works if this pattern matches only a single file like your question says, or if it matches more than one). `*/` will thus cut off everything up to and including the last slash in the string.